# Adding property to Edge removes connection to inV

Tags: graph, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

After running the command below, my Edge looks like this:

```
[
 {
 "id": "ee186ef3-5b0d-4257-a0ab-cc13dbac1c84",
 "label": "parent",
 "type": "edge",
 "outVLabel": "person",
 "outV": "74e99ad8-a6f8-4580-918c-2446acaae48c",
 "properties": {
  "type": "Mother",
  "age": "56"
  }
 }
]
```

Notice no inV on the Edge.

The command ran was this:

```
g.V('74e99ad8-a6f8-4580-918c-2446acaae48c')
 .inE('parent')
 .has('type', 'Mother')
 .property('age', '56')
```

Prior to running the command, the relationship was correct V -> E -> V

This was executed via a C# .net application

***** edit -- reproducing info ******

```
        var query = client.CreateGremlinQuery<dynamic>(graph, gremlin);
        var result = (await query.ExecuteNextAsync() as FeedResponse<object>);
```

Before running the command:

```
[{
"id": "7d3f2d1e-fb73-4e5d-a1b1-ea27fc429ce6",
"label": "parent",
"type": "edge",
"inVLabel": "person",
"outVLabel": "person",
"inV": "1c0d509f-6741-4555-8081-536b0c0b8667",
"outV": "f8da3c1c-0f32-4b5c-ace3-1673836807a1",
"properties": {
  "type": "Mother"
}
}]
```

The next step is to run this:

```
g.V('1c0d509f-6741-4555-8081-536b0c0b8667').inE('parent').has('type', 'Mother').property('age', '56')
```

The result back from the server:

```
{{
"id": "7d3f2d1e-fb73-4e5d-a1b1-ea27fc429ce6",
"label": "parent",
"type": "edge",
"inVLabel": "person",
"outVLabel": "person",
"inV": "1c0d509f-6741-4555-8081-536b0c0b8667",
"outV": "f8da3c1c-0f32-4b5c-ace3-1673836807a1",
"properties": {
  "type": "Mother"
}
}}
```

Right after the above, I run this:
g.E("7d3f2d1e-fb73-4e5d-a1b1-ea27fc429ce6")

Results:

```
[{
"id": "7d3f2d1e-fb73-4e5d-a1b1-ea27fc429ce6",
"label": "parent",
"type": "edge",
"outVLabel": "person",
"outV": "1c0d509f-6741-4555-8081-536b0c0b8667",
"properties": {
  "type": "Mother",
  "age": "56"
}
}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Microsoft.Azure.Graphs, please switch to Gremlin .Net

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-graph-dotnet

Gremlin .Net is the library recommended by Azure Cosmos DB and it contains the most recent features, bug fixes, and performance improvements.

Comment: I am using:

Azure.DocumentDB v1.22.0    
Azure.Graphs   v0.3.1-preview

            var query = client.CreateGremlinQuery<dynamic>(graph, gremlin);
            var result = (await query.ExecuteNextAsync() asFeedResponse<object>);

Comment: On the gremlin page: "Warning
Gremlin.Net does not yet have an official release. It is for developers who want to experiment with TinkerPop in the .NET ecosystem. "

Comment: FWIW - I'm using those libraries because of this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-graph-dotnet.

Comment: One of the authors of Gremlin.Net here: You can ignore that warning by now. Version 3.2.7 was the first official release of Gremlin.Net. We just forgot to remove the warning for that version, but it is removed now: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.9/reference/#gremlin-DotNet
Just make sure that you use a version 3.2.z for Cosmos DB as that doesn't support TinkerPop (and therefore Gremlin.Net) 3.3.z.

Comment: Not sure why this fixed it .. but changing to Gremlin.net fixed. Every other command worked ok with the MS driver, but adding that property caused side effects.